# What kind of drive is "NoRootDirectory " (System.IO.DriveType.NoRootDirectory)?

Tags: c#, drive

In C# `System.IO.DriveInfo` has the property `DriveType`.

`System.IO.DriveType` is an enum:

```
public enum DriveType
{
    Unknown = 0,
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The drive does not have a root directory.
    NoRootDirectory = 1,
    Removable = 2,
    Fixed = 3,
    Network = 4,
    CDRom = 5,
    Ram = 6,
}
```

I suspect that this is a volume without a drive letter. But using:

```
System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives();
```

doesn't list my volume without drive letter.

**Is `NoRootDirectory` used for any other type of volumes / drives or does `System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives()` just not show them?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`System.IO.DriveType.NoRootDirectory` seems to be an misleadingly designation for "**This drive letter is unused**"

Testcode for all drives: All not found drives have the type **DriveType.NoRootDirectory**

```
foreach (char driveLetter in "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".ToArray())
{
    var driveInfo = new System.IO.DriveInfo(driveLetter.ToString() + ":\\");

    if(System.IO.DriveInfo.GetDrives().FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name[0] == driveLetter) == null)
        Console.WriteLine("// Not found: " + driveInfo.Name + " has DriveType: " + driveInfo.DriveType.ToString());
    else
        Console.WriteLine("//     found: " + driveInfo.Name + " has DriveType: " + driveInfo.DriveType.ToString());
}
```

Result:

```
// Not found: A:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
// Not found: B:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
//     found: C:\ has DriveType: Fixed
//     found: D:\ has DriveType: CDRom
// Not found: E:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
// Not found: F:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
// Not found: G:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
// Not found: H:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
// Not found: I:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
// Not found: J:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
// Not found: K:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
// Not found: L:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
// Not found: M:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
// Not found: N:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
// Not found: O:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
//     found: P:\ has DriveType: Network
// Not found: Q:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
//     found: R:\ has DriveType: Network
//     found: S:\ has DriveType: Network
// Not found: T:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
// Not found: U:\ has DriveType: NoRootDirectory
//     found: V:\ has DriveType: Network
//     found: W:\ has DriveType: Fixed
//     found: X:\ has DriveType: Network
//     found: Y:\ has DriveType: Network
//     found: Z:\ has DriveType: Network
```

Comment: @HansPassant This is what I tested. Look at the edit.

Comment: How does this behave when facing a partition mounted into a folder in NTFS?

Answer (score 1):

I know that it's used for unassigned drive letters. You will of course not get them through `GetDrives` but try `new System.IO.DriveInfo("B:").DriveType` or such. It might be used for unformatted partitions (or unknown filesystems) as well, but I'm not totally sure (you would have to test whether you get `Unknown` or `NoRootDirectory` in that case). For completeness, you could also create garbage drives by going to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\DOS Devices` and creating a drive `X:` pointing to `\Device\Null` for example and see what you get for those.

Actually, the [documentation for the underlying WinAPI function `GetDriveType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364939(v=vs.85).aspx) is a bit clearer. It says:

> The root path is invalid; for example, there is no volume mounted at the specified path.

I would translate "the root path is invalid" as "The kernel path `\DosDevices\X:` doesn't resolve/link to a valid filesystem directory object able to resolve a request for the path `\`."

Probably the sentence was written by somebody with Windows kernel knowledge. In this case I'd assume that my "garbage drives" from above would also give you this value, as well as any unassigned drive letters.

For a more detailed read about the things I just mentioned, check out http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm%5eid=107.htm if you are interested.

Answer (score -2):

```
//Check fixed local drive
string path= "C\MyFolder\myfile.txt";
string root = Path.GetPathRoot(path);

if (DriveInfo.GetDrives().FirstOrDefault(d => d.Name == root).DriveType == DriveType.Fixed)
{
    MessageBox.Show(root);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.